# Ansible win_credentials failing ( asking for become although it is given)

Tags: ansible

Running ansible 2.9 on centos 7
to create a credential on windows_7 target

```
- name: "Save nw credentials for mapped drive {{ item.value.letter }}"
  win_credential:
    name: "{{ item.value.path }}"
    type: domain_password
    username: "DOMAIN\\{{ item.value.user }}"
    secret:  "{{ item.value.pass}}"
    state: present

  become: true
  become_method: runas
  become_flags: logon_type=new_credentials logon_flags=net_credentials_only
  vars:
    ansible_become_user: "{{ become_user  }}"
    ansible_become_password: "{{ become_passwd  }}"
```

I still get the error asking to run the module with become...

```
The full traceback is:
Exception calling "GetCredential" with "2" argument(s): "Failed to access the user's credential store, run the module with become"
At line:576 char:1
+ $existing_credential = [Ansible.CredentialManager.Credential]::GetCre ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidOperationException

ScriptStackTrace:
at <ScriptBlock>, <No file>: line 576
fatal: [FF-10]: FAILED! => {
    "changed": false, 
    "msg": "Unhandled exception while executing module: Exception calling \"GetCredential\" with \"2\" argument(s): \"Failed to access the user's credential store, run the module with become\""
}
```

Comment: Try deleting the line `become_flags: logon_type=new_credentials logon_flags=net_credentials_only`.

Answer (score 0):

In accordance to the test tasks in the module you should be able to use:

```
   12 - name: create domain user credential (check mode)
   13   win_credential:
   14     name: '{{ test_hostname }}'
   15     type: domain_password
   16     username: DOMAIN\username
   17     secret: password
   18     state: present
   19   register: domain_user_check
   20   check_mode: True
   21   vars: &become_vars
   22     ansible_become: True
   23     ansible_become_method: runas
   24     ansible_become_user: '{{ ansible_user }}'
   25     ansible_become_pass: '{{ ansible_password }}'
```

https://fossies.org/linux/ansible/test/integration/targets/win_credential/tasks/tests.yml